# How to do dotnet publish in Build Yaml

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-2.1

Can you please give an example the way to specify in build.yaml if needs to do `dotnet publish` a test project in `.Net Core 2.1`. referred [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) couldn't figure out exactly the way.

It says below, what should be the yaml way

> For this task to work, you must have already published the output of your build to this directory by using the dotnet publish --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) command. To copy additional files to this directory before publishing,

As example how below represent in `build.yaml` in class application (API Solution)

```
dotnet publish ~/projects/app1/app1.csproj
```

Tried below

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: "Prepare Publish Files"
      inputs:
        command: publish
        projects: ""
        arguments: --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/src/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests.csproj
```

But get below error, in fact mine is API solution where I am trying to publish end2end tests and run them after deployment.

```
##[error]No web project was found in the repository. Web projects are identified by presence of either a web.config file or wwwroot folder in the directory.
##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With below `YAML` code I was able to run the build

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet e2e tests"
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/src/xxx.EndToEnd.Integration.Tests
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

Explanation:

`publishWebProjects: false` - Since this is a API solution.

The easy way is to create task in designer wizard and see the YAML file there (Separate tab to show yaml file)